# Icon Adobe Reader DC on taskbar is wrong

Tags: taskbar, icons, adobe-reader

My icon adobe reader is now icon of Windows Photo Viewer on Taskbar.
How can I fix it?
I tried to uninstall or repair but it didn't work.

[image: IMG]

Comment: Try following this tutorial; [How to Reset and Clear All Pinned Apps on Taskbar in Windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3151-taskbar-pinned-apps-reset-clear-windows-10-a.html) if it works I will post a detailed answer.

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: I can't believe this problem is still not fixed in 2020.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Found it here : https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1113673?tstart=0

> 1. Remove, unpin or delete Adobe  Acrobat icon from the Start Menu, the desktop and (if you have it there) from the taskbar.
> 2. Go to C: > ProgramData > Microsoft > Windows > Start Menu > Programs  and you'll find the "sinner" "Adobe Acrobat XI Pro" with the
>      wrong icon. The that looks like a shortcut. Delete it!.. Close the
>      window.
> 3. Go to C: > Program Files (x86) > Adobe > Acrobat 11.0 > Acrobat... and find Acrobat.exe
> 4. Right click on Acrobat.exe > Send to > Desktop
> 5. Right click again on Acrobat.exe > Pin to Start Menu... and close the window
> 6. Right click on Acrobat.exe - shortcut (that you just created on your desktop) > Copy
> 7. Go back to: C: > ProgramData > Microsoft > Windows > Start Menu > Programs... and Paste the shortcut here (you need administrator
>      privileges for that)
> 8. Rename this shortcut from "Acrobat.exe - shortcut" to "Adobe Acrobat XI Pro"
> 9. Close the window
> 10. Now if you open any PDF document, the right icon will appear on the taskbar.

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing). You need to quote copied text that you didn't write. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: According to a now deleted answer: for some installations it might not be `Acrobat.exe` but `AcroRd32`.

Comment: I had figured this fix out on my own, but after a month or so it just happens again. I've yet to find a permanent solution.

Comment: Just had Acrobat reader update automatically, and it again installed at shortcut with wrong icon - this is definitely some weird bug in the Adobe installer!

Comment: I did a similar thing, but with Adobe DC, so this was really helpful thanks :)

Comment: I had no Pin to Start Menu option (step 5), so I just renamed the shortcut on the Desktop, copied the remained shortcut back to the Start Menu >> Programs folder (step 7), deleted the shortcut on the Desktop, dragged the shortcut in the Start Menu to the pinned shortcuts area, and it worked. :)

Comment: Same problem with Adobe DC, and i think this is the fix too.

Answer (score 22):

I didn't try the [existing solution posted by Shivam here](https://superuser.com/a/1012536/333291), but, rather got another workaround (solution) from the thread [**Adobe Reader icon not showing on Windows 10**](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1937623).

The workaround (solution) was as simple as to change the default application for .ico files to Microsoft Paint.

[image]

[image]

This solved the problem for the poster as well as for me, :) - (Looks like a bug with the Adobe Acrobat Installer package for Windows 10.)

Comment: but the "fixed" icon doesn't seem to be the new red border back in fill logo

Comment: @DanielCheung - Would you elaborate a bit more? I didn't get what you meant!

Comment: The icon became https://botw-pd.s3.amazonaws.com/styles/logo-thumbnail/s3/0017/9729/brand.gif?itok=Bovi-ZIv, not https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/4c/Acrobat_Pro_CC_icon.svg/240px-Acrobat_Pro_CC_icon.svg.png. The latter is the latest logo.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: This is probably not a workaround but a fix to the source of the problem.